# J2ME: JSON Serialization/De-Serialization

Tags: json, serialization, java-me, lwuit

I want to serialize and de-serialize (from a POJO) JSON objects for **J2ME**. I did go through few tools available like GSON etc. Since they use Java reflection, J2ME doesn't support the same.

Answer (score 2):

`JSONParser` is a part of LWUIT4IO although it has a few bugs that were only fixed in [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/). Codename One also contains a JSON/XML processing package similar to XPATH.